# Push to a POST API using Pub/Sub

Tags: .net, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, android-management-api

I'm setting up [Pub/Sub](https://developers.google.com/android/management/notifications) for my `Android Management API` solution, I have created a `Topic` & `Subscription` to create a `ENROLLMENT` notification. The subscription is of type `PULL` so when I pull it works as expected and shows the enrollment notifications.

I want to use `Delivery type` as `PUSH` and hit a `POST API` which will add the details of this newly enrolled device into my DB.
Can I use the `POST API URL` something like `https://abc.dcd.com:8008/api/PubTest` as the `Endpoint URL`? If so how can I test it using debugger ?

I was unable to find any tutorial in C# to do the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Here are the docs on push subscriptions ... https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push ... maybe see if you can study these for a bit and see if they assist.  It appears that a push subscription does use an HTTPS POST as requested.  For using Pub/Sub in C# ... https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/using-pub-sub  and https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/

Comment: @Kolban, thanks! Will check out the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t see anything obviously wrong with using something like `https://abc.dcd.com:8008/api/PubTest` as the endpoint URL. A Pub/Sub push request looks like the following (note that the `message.data` field is base64-encoded).

```
POST https://abc.dcd.com:8008/api/PubTest

{
  "message": {
    "attributes": {
      "key": "value"
    },
    "data": "SGVsbG8gQ2xvdWQgUHViL1N1YiEgSGVyZSBpcyBteSBtZXNzYWdlIQ==",
    "messageId": "136969346945"
  },
  "subscription": "projects/MY_PROJECT/subscriptions/MY_SUBSCRIPTION"
}
```

To configure your subscription to deliver messages to a push endpoint, you can configure it directly in the Google Cloud Console via the ‘Create subscription’ or ‘Edit subscription’ page.

[Screenshot of the Google Cloud Console's 'Edit subscription' page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZOH7.png)

You can also configure your subscription using gcloud.

```
$ gcloud pubsub subscriptions update \
  projects/MY_PROJECT/subscriptions/MY_SUBSCRIPTION \
  --push-endpoint https://abc.dcd.com:8008/api/PubTest
```

For more information, please refer to the following guide for using push subscriptions: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've actually achieved it a while ago forgot to update here.

Now I am facing an issue where I get Enrollment Notification on ```PROVISIONING``` but I'd like to get once the device ```STATE``` : ```ACTIVE```, any help with this?

Comment: I'd suggest creating a separate question about how to get specific device notifications with the tag android-management-api, since this question is more about how to configure a Cloud Pub/Sub subscription with a push endpoint.